# Is there a way to allow an image to extend past the boundary of the window?

Tags: android, background, imageview

I'm trying (and not finding) a way to have an image that acts as a background, which is larger than the the screen, to not squish and instead to just flow off the right and bottom of the screen.

In other words, I have a background image that is, say, 3000x3000 pixels.

I want it to originate at 0x0 and then rather than being squished into whatever the resolution of the device is, to just get naturally cropped by said resolution, allowing the excess to flow off the sides.

I've tried every combination of wrapping content and scaleType(ing) that I can think of and none of them produce the intended result.  Is there a way to do this? Or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setScaleType to MATRIX and call setClipChildren with false on the parent ViewGroup container

Comment: ok setClipChildren is needless if your ImageView spans the whole screen